# Windows Server 2008 R2 Shared folders are very slow when uploading files

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, server-message-block, network-share, cifs

I have a little problem, I have a server with Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise edition with the File Service installed, and a client with Windows 7 Pro.

Everything works fine but the file transfert via SMB from the client to the server is VERY slow, the network is gigabits and the transfer rate is not stable at all (I'm the only to use the network):

Server to Client : Stable, shown at ~44MBps

Client to Server : The shown speed is between 16MBps and 5MBps (Average = 10MBps), while looking on the network graph of the Task manager, I see a lot of peek, it send the file, stop for 1 or 2 seconds, continue to send the file, re-stop, etc...

Any idea of what can be this problem and how to fix it ?
I checked the DNS but there isn't any Error.
Thank you

EDIT: I tried with another computer as client (MacOsX), and same problem when uploading (but slower when downloading).